# Creating dynamic image gallery using angularjs and bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, html5-canvas

How do I create a dynamic image gallery to show thumbnails using angularjs and bootstrap where images will be dynamically added on load. Also it should fit in mobiles, desktops and tablets.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure `jQuery` and `AngularJS` are both loaded through `script` tags. jQuery must be loaded first because Angular uses jQuery.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
```

To use Angular code in your HTML views, you need to bootstrap your application with the `ng-app` directive. Set it's value equal to what you declared in your JavaScript file. You can place this directive anywhere you like, but the best places are either the `html` or `body` tags.

Your controllers are what connects the `scope` with your view. You need to use the `ng-controller` directive in order to use this scope.

Bootstrap uses the grid system. You want to nest a div with class `row` inside your `container` and inside another class taking up 3/4 of the screen on tablets and desktops and the full-width on mobile devices.

To make images responsive, bootstrap has an `img-responsive` class. Using angular, you can have an array of image data, and use `ng-repeat` to iterate over each image. I think the best way to do this would be through a hash.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
          <img class="img-responsive" ng-repeat="image in images" ng-src="image.src" alt="{{image.alt}}" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.images = [
            { "src": "image1.png", "alt": "First Image" }, 
            { "src": "image2.png", "alt": "Second image" }, 
            { "src": "image3.png", "alt": "Third image" }, 
            { "src": "image4.png", "alt": "Fourth image" }
        ];
    }]);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Try this codepen](http://codepen.io/benjaminsweetnam247/pen/gaxWQQ)

Using AngularJS, css and html you can simply do it.

HTML

```
<h1>angular gallery</h1>
<div ng-app="gallery">
  <div ng-controller="GalleryCtrl"><gallery></gallery></div>
</div>
```

AngularJS

```
angular.module('gallery', [])
.controller('GalleryCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 $scope.pictures = [
{name:"first", 
 img:"http://placehold.it/200?text=first"
},
{name:"second", 
 img:"http://placehold.it/200?text=second"},
{name:"third", 
 img:"http://placehold.it/200?text=third"},
{name:"fourth", 
 img:"http://placehold.it/200?text=fourth"},
{name:"fifth", 
 img:"http://placehold.it/200?text=fifth"},
{name:"sixth", 
 img:"http://placehold.it/200?text=sixth"},
{name:"seventh", 
 img:"http://placehold.it/200?text=seventh"},
{name:"eighth", 
 img:"http://placehold.it/200?text=eighth"},
 ]
 }])
.directive('gallery', function() {
 return {
 replace: true,
 restrict: 'E',
 controller: 'GalleryCtrl',
 template: '\
  <div class="gallery">\
  <div class="picture" ng-repeat="picture in pictures">\
    <img src="{{ picture.img }}">\
  </div>\
</div>'
}
});
```